# Hard code the nextpage tag into my theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have a custom post type for a Slideshow which uses Custom Post Meta to insert the different slides. How can I code the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in between the sides in my slideshow.php so that they slides will paginate? Right now when I try to do it the code doesn't show because it by it's nature it commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was more extensively discussed at Hybrid support forum. I made and posted snippet for [custom pagination of custom fields content](http://themehybrid.com/support/topic/hard-coding-the-nextpage-tag-into-my-theme#post-46016) there.

Comment: If you've got nothing better to do and would like to help the larger issue I was trying to solve with this, it's posted here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/help-creating-a-slideshow-custom-post-type-with-custom-meta-boxes :)

Answer (score 1):

Inserting  into your theme does not make much sense, because it's parsed prior theme display. You need to have that in your posts content prior to display (that means in `$post->post_content` when queried). This might not already be the case, so a reason why you currently experience that it is not paginating. The other reason why this happens is an incompatible theme.

The function that takes care about pagination in post templates (templates are a theme related part in wordpress) is called [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages). You theme must support the multipage global variables otherwise this will never work. Those global variables are: `$page, $pages, $multipage, $more, $numpages`. You can learn more about their usage in [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) (undocumented function, see [`setup_postdata()` in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php#L3202)).

So if you manage to get all the `<!--nextpage-->` fragments into your posts content and your theme supports multi pages for that custom post type template, you should be fine. The wp_link_pages() function might be handy to achieve this.

Comment: My theme supports it so that is not an issue.  I'm using custom post meta fields for the post content so technically, I"m not actually using the_content.  I guess what I'm asking then if I can't utilize `<!--nextpage-->` inside my theme files, how can I hard code a page break into a theme?

Comment: If you don't use the_content / $post->post_content then you're left alone on your own and maybe the best thing you could do w/o coding a whole paging business logic on *your style of having content managed* is to call `wp_link_pages()` on your own. And/Or to reuse the global variables I named.

Answer (score 0):

for me `<!-- nextpage -->` is not working for any theme.
Check the post http://article-stack.com/education/web-design-n-development/blog-blogger-blogging/xampp-how-to-run-test-wordpress-locally.amty

Comment: Please create separate question for your issue, this is neither answer or relevant information for this question.